# how to access nested object methods in java

Tags: java

I have several classes with their own attributes and methods(say leaf classes). I want to create objects of these leaf classes and make them members of other classes (say composite classes). Each composite class has variable number of leaf objects and some methods in it.I should be able to create objects of the composite classes and access methods within that composite class easily. But how do I access the methods of the leaf class objects contained within the composite class?

```
interface Leaf{
//methods common to all leaf classes
}

class LeafA implements Leaf{
//attributes
// interface method implementations
//methods unique to this class
}

class LeafB implements Leaf{
//attributes
// interface method implementations
//methods unique to this class
}


class LeafC implements Leaf{
//attributes
// interface method implementations
//methods unique to this class
}

interface Composite{
//common methods
}

class CompositeOne implements Composite{
//attributes 
//list of one or more leaf objects
//methods unique to this class
}

class CompositeTwo implements Composite{
//attributes 
//list of one or more leaf objects
//methods unique to this class
}
```

My doubt is how to access the methods inside the leaf classes using the object of composite class.

Comment: Not sure I understand the issue you're having. If those objects have public methods, why can't you just call the public methods? What happened when you tried?

Comment: I think you are trying the wrong approach... the point of the composite pattern is to be able to pass any Leaf implementation and treat them the same way. If you want something specific to LeafA for example, you would need to do something like a downcast from Leaf to LeafA, but you should make sure that you will always have a LeafA instance where you are doing the casting, which kind of defeats the purpose of having a polimorphic interface

Answer (score 0):

Your `Composite` interface has a purpose that is different from that of the `Leaf` type. This is the reason why having methods for handling `Leaf` operations in `Composite` is not a good idea (concerns are not separated). With that said, that's technically possible although it's just a questionable design decision.

One alternative option you may have is to create a different interface that's about doing the **common composite-level things you want to do on `Leaf` instances** in composite-level classes. For example:

```
interface LeafProcessor {
    void processLeaves();
}
```

This interface can then be implemented by your current `CompositeOne` and `CompositeTwo` classes. Example:

```
class CompositeOne implements Composite, LeafProcessor{
    //attributes 
    Leaf leafA = new LeafA();
    //methods unique to this class

    @Override
    public void processLeaves() {
        this.leafA.doSomething();
    }
}
```

Note that this class implements 2 interfaces. Of course, this fact probably warrants a new name for the `CompositeOne` class.

You will have to decide what you decide to implement this by (such as `CompositeLeafAProcessor` that will only have instances of `LeafA`, etc.)